# Difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I had an argument with my colleagues over the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Excel 2007. I said the main difference is that in 64-bit version, we'll be able to add more than 65536 rows where as in 32-bit we won't be able to add more than 65536 rows.

Please clarify this.

Comment: looks like you lost the argument. time to fess up to your colleagues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, both 32 and 64 bit versions support more than 65536 rows, and have done since Excel 2007 was released.

The main difference is that you can work with very large workbooks in the 64 bit version.  The downside of the 64 bit version is that, at present, there is poor support from 3rd party add-ins.

**Update**

This was written back in 2011. I'm sure that support for 3rd party add-ins is better now. However, it may still be an issue, and before installing the 64 bit version it is worth checking that all your required tools that are built on top of Excel are compatible with the 64 bit version.

Comment: 64-bit version only exists for Excel 2010. Ecel 2007 is only 32 bit app

Comment: @mas The question talks about 64 bit 2007. This answer does not. It's presumably just a trivial slip by the person asking the question. Does it really deserve a downvote?

Comment: Actually, support for third party Excel add-ins (.xlam files) was not particularly poor for 64-bit Excel, unless the add-in included calls to the Windows APIs. A given add-in is not 32- or 64-bit, but simply loads in the version of Excel which is running. Support for COM add-ins is what suffers, since the most popular language for those, VB6, only works in 32-bit. Dot-Net add-ins can be compiled in either 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: @Jon My Delphi COM add-in had to wait for Embarcadero to ship a 64 bit compiler

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2007 has only a 32-bit version. Excel 2010 introduced the 64-bit option, which Microsoft actually doesn't recommend unless you really really need it for huge databases.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that the 32 bit version only has access to 2GB of memory. Very large integer calculations *might* also be faster in the 64 bit version.

Both versions can deal with more than 65536 rows.

Comment: There is no 64-bit Excel 2007 version. If the OS is 64 bit, it still works in 32 bit mode

Comment: I never said there was. Why not just upvote Jon instead of downvoting everyone else's valid information?